# Trying to Subclass PFUser with Swift - What Am I Missing?

Tags: parse-platform

I am working with Parse, and I am trying to subclass `PFUser` to add some additional properties: `gamerFirstName`, `gamerLastName`, `gamerUsername`, `gamerEmail`, `gamerPassword`.

When on the signup view controller, I take the entered values from the text fields and create a `Gamer` struct:

[image: Gamer Struct screenshot from Xcode]

Next, I create my `PFUser` subclass, which is called `ParseGamer`:

[image: ParseGamer PFUser subclass screenshot from Xcode]

Then, I create a `ParseOperation` struct to handle operations that I do with Parse:

[image: Parse Operation Struct screenshot from Xcode]

Finally, I register my `PFUser` subclass, `ParseGamer`, in my `AppDelegate`:

[image: App Delegate registration of subclass screenshot from Xcode]

I'm quite uncertain what I am doing incorrectly, but when I click on my signup button, I get a response from Parse that says "*[Error]: Cannot sign up without a username. (Code: 200, Version: 1.9.1)*".

Can anyone point out to me what I seem to be missing? It seems as though Parse is trying to sign up a `PFUser` rather than a `ParseGamer` because the response error is what you receive when using the `PFUser` class and don't enter a username. Also, I'm not using `username`, but instead I'm wanting to use `gamerUsername`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages says it all: you MUST use "username" field. You can't create your own username field.